# C malloc segmentation fault struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault, malloc

In the textbook my teacher provided us, there is this C code's sample, which when I try to run gives a Segmentation Fault error:

```
const celula *nulo = NULL;
typedef char informacao;
typedef celula *noh;
typedef celula *arvore;
struct celula {informacao info; noh pai; noh fesq; noh idir;};

...

typedef struct celfloresta celfloresta;
typedef struct celfloresta *floresta;
typedef struct celfloresta *posicfloresta;
struct celfloresta {arvore elem; celfloresta *prox;};

...

void FormarListaNohs(){
    floresta p = (floresta)malloc(sizeof(celfloresta));
    p->elem->info = '3';
}

...
```

Why does the line 
`p->elem->info = '3';`
give segmentation fault here?

Comment: Need to `malloc` memory for `elem` too.

Comment: regarding: `const celula *nulo = NULL;`  This is using the `celula` before it is defined.  Suggest moving that statement to after the definition of the struct

Comment: OT: regarding: `floresta p = (floresta)malloc(sizeof(celfloresta));`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code.  Suggest removing the cast.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: OT: regarding: `typedef struct celfloresta *floresta;` and `typedef struct celfloresta *posicfloresta;`  and typedef celula *noh;` and `typedef celula *arvore;`  It is a very poor programming practice (and very misleading to the human reader of the code) to hide pointers in a `typedef`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`elem` is a pointer. You need to allocate memory for it:

```
p->elem = malloc(sizeof(arvore));
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically malloc return a void pointer then to cast is should use a variable of type pointer
an example :

```
int *p = malloc(sizeof(int))
struct s_list *l = malloc(sizeof(struct s_list))
```

then you can dereference the pointer for example

```
l->data = 12;
```